# Python Selenium can't click the button after upgrading OS and firefox

Tags: python, selenium

I was using Selenium to click the "NIGHT SESSION" button of this web page

https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Futures-and-Options-Prices/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures-and-Options?sc_lang=en#&product=HSI

The html source is like this:

```
<span class="ns ns_night">NIGHT SESSION</span>
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re, time

geckodriver = '/opt/geckodriver'

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('-headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckodriver, firefox_options=options)

driver.get('https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Futures-and-Options-Prices/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures-and-Options?sc_lang=en#&product=HSI')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/span[@class="ns ns_night"]'))).click()
```

It worked fine on CentOS 7 with Firefox-60.6.1, Geckodriver v.0.24.0, Python 3.6.8, selenium 3.141.0

But it no longer click the button after I upgrade to CentOS 8 with Firefox-91.4.0, Geckodriver v.0.31.0, Python 3.6.8, selenium 3.141.0

Any clue?  Thanks.

Comment: It works on my machine ('.. then we'll ship your machine!' yeah, I know how Docker was born). Anyway, thing is, your code is valid, so maybe try updating your pip, and pip packages.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.  How can I debug?  For example, how can I know if I can click the button?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OP's code works. I'm posting this response as an example of how to naively debug the code above, and to make sure it does what it's supposed to do. Selenium setup is for linux/debian, using Firefox/geckodriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as Firefox_Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t
import pandas as pd

firefox_options = Firefox_Options()

# firefox_options.add_argument("--width=1280")
# firefox_options.add_argument("--height=720")

driverService = Service('chromedriver/geckodriver')

browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=driverService, options=firefox_options)
actions = ActionChains(browser)
browser.get('https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Futures-and-Options-Prices/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures-and-Options?sc_lang=en#&product=HSI')
day_table = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'equity_future')))
print('loaded the page, we should see the Day Session data by default. See below: ')
t.sleep(5)
day_df = pd.read_html(day_table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]

print(day_df)
print('now we will click on the Night session button')
t.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/span[@class="ns ns_night"]'))).click()
print('clicked!')
print('now we will define again the table holding the data, see if it changed')
t.sleep(2)
night_table = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'equity_future')))
print('ok, found the table, is it different from the one above?')
night_df = pd.read_html(night_table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
print(night_df)
```

This should output in the terminal:

```
loaded the page, we should see the Day Session data by default. See below: 
Contract    Last Traded Net Change  Prev.Day Settlement Price   Bid Ask Open    High Low    Volume  Prev.Day Open Interest
Total   Unnamed: 1_level_1  Unnamed: 2_level_1  Unnamed: 3_level_1  Unnamed: 4_level_1  Unnamed: 5_level_1  Unnamed: 6_level_1  98,679  144,822
0   Aug-22  20027   +461    19566.0 2001620029  19848   2007619761  97696   118174
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   Sep-22  19960   +455    19505.0 1990020023  19791   2001319716  717 13915
3   Oct-22  20020   +467    19553.0 --  20020   2002020020  1   3
4   Nov-22  -   -   19557.0 --  -   --  -   -
5   Dec-22  20126   +504    19622.0 1939120300  19851   2012619851  234 10872
6   Mar-23  20180   +468    19712.0 1850020455  19958   2020019935  31  78
7   Jun-23  -   -   19580.0 --  -   --  -   -
8   Dec-23  -   -   19590.0 --  -   --  -   1775
9   Jun-24  -   -   19534.0 --  -   --  -   -
10  Dec-24  -   -   19538.0 --  -   --  -   3
11  Dec-25  -   -   19508.0 --  -   --  -   2
12  Dec-26  -   -   18746.0 --  -   --  -   -
13  Dec-27  -   -   18744.0 --  -   --  -   -
now we will click on the Night session button
clicked!
now we will define again the table holding the data, see if it changed
ok, found the table, is it different from the one above?
Contract    Last Traded Net Change  Prev.Day Settlement Price   Bid Ask Open    High Low    Volume  Prev.Day Open Interest
Total   Unnamed: 1_level_1  Unnamed: 2_level_1  Unnamed: 3_level_1  Unnamed: 4_level_1  Unnamed: 5_level_1  Unnamed: 6_level_1  0   144,822
0   Aug-22  -   -   19566.0 2001620059  -   --  -   118174
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   Sep-22  -   -   19505.0 1990020023  -   --  -   13915
3   Oct-22  -   -   19553.0 --  -   --  -   3
4   Nov-22  -   -   19557.0 --  -   --  -   -
5   Dec-22  -   -   19622.0 1920020300  -   --  -   10872
6   Mar-23  -   -   19712.0 1850020455  -   --  -   78
7   Jun-23  -   -   19580.0 --  -   --  -   -
8   Dec-23  -   -   19590.0 --  -   --  -   1775
9   Jun-24  -   -   19534.0 --  -   --  -   -
10  Dec-24  -   -   19538.0 --  -   --  -   3
11  Dec-25  -   -   19508.0 --  -   --  -   2
12  Dec-26  -   -   18746.0 --  -   --  -   -
13  Dec-27  -   -   18744.0 --  -   --  -   -
```

As we can see, tables **are** different. Pip freeze (to see packages versions) looks like this on my system:

```
[...]
selenium==4.3.0
selenium-browser==0.0.15
[..]
```

Lastly, Selenium documentation can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/